# SwiftUi how to display a keyboard with numpad in the side

Tags: swiftui, keyboard, numpad

I need to display a full keyboard in my app with a numpad in the side, like the one I screenshot from a Boeing App.

I try the .keyboardType(.numberPad) and many other Modifiers, but I could not get the same keyboard as the App from Boeing mentioned before.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

[Keyboard I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7i6w.jpg)

Comment: Make your own, that isn’t an apple keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic Apple keyboard includes numbers on the second page. I would just use that if you need characters and numbers, or use the `.numberPad` if you need only numbers. Unless you're using this keyboard for fullscreen iOS or the iPad, your screenshot looks too wide too for the UI to work. Additionally, building a keyboard would be a lot of work for any benefits your custom keyboard might provide.

Here's a working example of a custom keyboard to get you started. Obviously you'll need to work on the appearance and adding some more buttons, but this will illustrate the basic structure of what you want.

```
struct CustomKeybaord: View {

    @State var text: String = ""

    let topCharacters: [String] = ["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I","O", "P"]
    let topMiddleCharacters: [String] = ["A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L"]
    let bottomMiddleCharacters: [String] = ["Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M"]

    func keyboardTap(character: String) {
        self.text += character
    }
                                    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(text)
            HStack {
                ForEach(topCharacters, id: \.self) { character in
                    KeyboardButton(character: character, color: .white, function: keyboardTap)
                        .padding(5)
                }
            }
        
            HStack {
                ForEach(topMiddleCharacters, id: \.self) { character in
                    KeyboardButton(character: character, color: .white, function: keyboardTap)
                        .padding(5)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 50)
        
            HStack {
                ForEach(bottomMiddleCharacters, id: \.self) { character in
                    KeyboardButton(character: character, color: .white, function: keyboardTap)
                        .padding(5)
                }
            
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 75)
        }
        .background(Color.init(white: 0.9))
        .frame(height: 100)
    }
 }

struct KeyboardButton: View {
    let character: String
    let color: Color
    var function: (String) -> Void
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            function(character)
        } label: {
            Text(character)
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(color)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
    }
}
```

You'll also want to abstract away the `HStack`ed `ForEach`s into an intermediate view.

The hardest thing left for you to do is find a way to calculate the key button sizes responsibly. Unless you want them to be a fixed size (which would be a bad idea, because it wouldn't work for any but one iPad size) you'll have figure out a way to calculate a universal button size based on the overall screen width using `GeometryReader`. In my example I use `frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)` to give each each button in a row the same size, but this doesn't ensure that buttons on different rows will be the same size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need to have faster selection between numbers and characters. The switching between the first and second page is to slow for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you working with landscape mode or with the iPad? Your design looks like it make the keys too small for a portrait mode iphone.

Comment: If you are going to be designing a custom keyboard, consider putting the numbers along the top so the keyboard isn't too wide for the screen

Comment: The App im designing is only intended to be used in landscape on the iPad. For what I see I have to study, how to make a Keyboard of my own now.

Comment: Here I'll respond with my attempt in a minute...

Comment: See edited answer...